# Hyperlink to return to a previous slide

Tags: beamer, hyperlink, frame

I am trying to use `\hyperlink{}{}` to return to a previous slide using `beamer`.

I am doing the following:

```
        % SLIDE 31
        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{ML 1}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 1}
        \label{restriçao}
        Some text and equations here
        \end{frame}

        % SLIDE 32
        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{ML 1}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some information here;
\item More information here.
\end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        % SLIDE 33
        \subsection{SVM 2}
        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{ML 2}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some info;
\item Here i am trying to use \hyperlink{restriçao}{minimization}.
\end{itemize}
        \end{frame}
```

But when i click in the hyperlink generated, instead of going back to the Slide 31 it goes back to the first slide on my presentation.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The command `\label{restriçao}` tries to associate the string `restriçao` with the most recently incremented counter variable. If no counter variableds have been incremented throughout the document, the only possible "anchor" is the very beginning of the document.

Comment: See `\hyperlinkslideprev` (page 109).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\label{restriçao}` tells LaTeX to associate the string `restriçao` with the most recently incremented counter variable. If no counter variableds have been incremented throughout the document, the only possible "anchor" is the very beginning of the document.

What you should do then, is to replace `\label{restriçao}` with `\hypertarget{restriçao}{}`. Note that `\hypertarget` takes two arguments. The first will be used as the "anchor", the second (which is optional) for some text you wish to display.

Unless you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you should *not* employ non-ASCII characters, such as `ç`, in the first argument of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`.

I would thus rewrite your code as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

        % SLIDE 31
        \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{ML 1}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 1}
        %%%\label{restricao}
        \hypertarget{restricao}{}  % <-- new
        Some text and equations here
        \end{frame}

        % SLIDE 32
        \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{ML 1}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 1}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Some information here;
        \item More information here.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        % SLIDE 33
        \subsection{SVM 2}
        \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{ML 2}
        \framesubtitle{SVM 2}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Some info;
        \item Here i am trying to use \hyperlink{restricao}{minimization}.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh great, thanks! I guess the problem was really the non-ASCII character.